# courses.copy function in Google Classroom API

Tags: api, google-classroom

We can not currently find a 'courses.copy' function in the API, is this available?

Use case: We have 100+ "Master" Google Classrooms from which we copy to allow all resources and classroom structure (topics, etc) to duplicate and be added as *drafts* in the new copy. Our dev team is automating the duplication of new courses based on Master classrooms.

Thanks for your support,
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately an API to copy classes is not available.

The feature itself is only available under the web
you can find the reference here [a link](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/9093680)!

It could be a good feature or idea to be implemented in the future, you can share here [feature request](https://developers.google.com/classroom/support)!